# PHP Failed to open stream (Weird)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

> **Note:** Working in my local, but not in my dev(live) site.

[image]

**Server details (dev-live)**

- PHP 7.0
- Nginx 1.10.0
- Composer

**Steps to reproduce issue**

- Clone repo
- Composer install (php artisan optimise specifically)
- The error output on screenschot above (RuntimeException)

**To DO to check if the file exist**

- First, I copied the "directory error" and paste it on terminal. On screenshot above, I got an error saying also "No such file or directory".
- Second, I type the whole directory with the same directory. Then I can OPEN it.

I find it so weird and I don't have idea why its happening. Can you point out whats wrong it this thing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the error message(s) in text form in your question, rather than in a hard-to-read external image.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `composer install` via root its can happen.

> Certain Composer commands, including exec, install, and update allow third party code to execute on your system. This is from its "plugins" and "scripts" features. Plugins and scripts have full access to the user account which runs Composer. For this reason, it is strongly advised to avoid running Composer as super-user/root.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md

Comment: Hi moshe, it is not on composer. Its error when composer runs the "PHP ARTISAN OPTIMIZE" command.

Comment: @AlexJohnSuarez Are you run the `composer install` under root user?
Check if the file exists with root user.

Comment: oh I run it with another user, not in root.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file is in the backoffice folder?
**If it does not, the recommendation to install from scratch may not match up if you've probably experimented with setup or a local server.**

Comment: Yes As I have stated above, When I copy and paste the Error(output directory) - no such file or directory. But when I type with the same directory, I can open it.

Comment: Did you have a setup from scratch?

Comment: Yes setup it from scratch.